# Order of win32api functions causing callback function to receive the same message

Tags: c, winapi, callback, messagebox, sendmessage

I have a resource file (.rc) which contains the following

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 500, 106
BEGIN

    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK", IDOK,            174, 18, 50, 14

    RADIOBUTTON     "Radio 1", ID_RADIOBUTTON1, 226, 18, 55, 14
END
```

My C file contains the following

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case ID_RADIOBUTTON1:
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, "RadioButton 1", "111", MB_OK);
                SendMessage((HWND)lParam, (UINT) BM_SETCHECK, (WPARAM) BST_CHECKED,(LPARAM)NULL);
            }
        return TRUE;
        break;

        }
    break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
        return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUT), NULL, AboutDlgProc);
}
```

Upon clicking the radio button once after the dialog box has opened the callback function repeatedly receives the same message which is a WM_COMMAND with the LOWORD(wParam) == ID_RADIOBUTTON1. But if SendMessage is called before MessageBox then the error doesn't happen. Is there a specific reason for this?

EDIT

---

But if I replace the call to MessageBox with printf then the error doesn't happen and the behaviour is as expected and only a single instance of output is produced.

I'm using gcc and windres to make the program.

My OS is Windows Vista(tm) Home Premium 32 bit Service Pack 2

Comment: You're missing a semicolon

Comment: Sorry... I edited it poorly

Comment: From half a mile away without testing it: BM_SETCHECK will generate a BN_CLICK notification.  Which is wrapped in a WM_COMMAND notification.  So moving the SendMessage call get you to choose between burning 100% core on the UI thread or getting a screen full of message boxes.  Break the loop by only sending BM_SETCHECK when the radio button *needs* to be checked.  Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AUTORADIOBUTTON` (instead of `RADIOBUTTON`) This will automatically set the selection mark. For example:

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOGEX 0, 0, 222, 257
STYLE DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SETFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 9, "Segoe UI", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK", IDOK,  174, 18, 50, 14
    AUTORADIOBUTTON "Radio 1", ID_RADIOBUTTON1, 226, 18, 55, 14
END
```

You can use `MessageBox` or other modal windows:

```
...
case ID_RADIOBUTTON1:
{
    MessageBox...
}
```

For `RADIOBUTTON` you have to set the selection mark yourself. Do this as soon as possible and return `TRUE` immediately. Don't call `MessageBox` before or after:

```
case ID_RADIOBUTTON1:
    SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_SETCHECK, !IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, ID_RADIOBUTTON1), 0);
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: ps, in Visual Studio 2015 I couldn't duplicate the same errors you are describing (I did duplicates some errors/misbehavior) Maybe you are using a different IDE.

Comment: But why not call MessageBox, is there a specific reason for not doing so? Also please see my edit in the question for further information.

Comment: I was able to duplicate your error in Visual Studio 2008 ----- You should use `"AUTORADIOBUTTON"`, then you can use a `MessageBox`. The problem is that you are using `"RADIOBUTTON"` which is old. You are setting the selection in response to setting the selection, this can easily get stuck in a loop.